How to determine the structure of the compound C12H8 knowing the following properties?

Hydrocarbon A has the formula C12H8. It absorbs 8 equivalents of H2 on catalytic reduction over a palladium catalyst. On ozonolysis, only two products are formed: oxalic acid (HO2CCO2H) and succinic acid (HO2CCH2CH2CO2H). Propose a structure for A.

The degree of unsaturation for A is 9 and the 8 equivalents tell us that there are 8 complex bonds. This means that there must exist one cycle in A. The options for the complex bonds are:

8 double bonds
4 triple bonds
2 double bonds, 3 triple bonds
4 double bonds, 2 triple bonds,
6 double bonds, 1 triple bond

The ozonolysis part implies the existence of some triple bonds, but from then on I am stuck.

Starting from acids would be better idea - they already imply triple bonds.

The solution of this problem is based on a cycle with 12 carbon atoms. In this cycle, four carbon atoms are joined by single bonds, being later ozonolysed into succinic acid. At the end of this group of 4 atoms, a double bond joins both ends of this 4-atoms block to the rest of the cycle. The rest of the cycle is made of alternating simple and triple bonds.

There are two saturated linkers corresponding to succinic acid, like here: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0040403900777896

Unsubstituted cyclododeca-1,3,7,9-tetrayne quickly polymerised, though, so I wonder how anyone could conduct its ozonolysis ;>

The degree of unsaturation of the proposed formula is incorrect, though. I figured it out - the compound is cyclododeca-1,3,7,9-tetrayne, as Mithoron pointed out.
